# Курсор внутри тегов Sublime Text 3

Tags: html

Раньше после создания любого тега в ST3 например div+TAB курсор становился в центре

```
<div>|</div>
```

и если после этого нажимаешь ENTER то он становился вот так:

```
<div>
  |(тут курсор)
</div>
```

после обновления ST3, нажимая на ENTER закрывающий див просто переносится на новую строку вот так:

```
<div>
|</div>
```

Как сделать, что бы было как раньше?

Установлены плагины Emmet и Tag

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences -> Key Bindings-User

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "auto_indent_tag", "context":
[
    { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "punctuation.definition.tag.begin", "match_all": true },
    { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": ">$", "match_all": true },
    { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^</", "match_all": true },
]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, только что проверил. Это именно то, что надо!